Jest + PhpStorm: this._convertStringToNumber is not a function
I get the following error when I try to equate two objects that are not the same in Jest in PhpStorm:

TypeError: this._convertStringToNumber is not a function

IDE: PhpStorm 2024.2.0.1
Jest: 29.7.0
I have no ideas how to fix it.
Expected result: show the differences between the objects.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
